# Asp.net 4 url rewrite a subdomain as a folder

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

What I'm trying to do is the following, I want to rewrite this kind of url:

```
blog.domain.com/...
```

into

```
domain.com/blog/...
```

It's in a shared host environment, using IIS7/ASP.Net 4. Another thing is that both the domain and the blog subdomain have different aps running. I've been searching for hours for what's the best solution here, and I hope someone can guide me a bit here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt as first idea.

```
    // keep a valid list somewhere
    List<string> cValidNames = new List<string>();
    cValidNames.Add("blog");

    // get the host
    //string TheHost = Request.Url.Host;
    string TheHost = "blog.domain.com";

    // find the first part, assume that the domain is standard and not change
    int WhereStarts = TheHost.IndexOf(".domain.com");

    // if we found it
    if(WhereStarts != -1)
    {
        string cTheFirstPart = TheHost.Substring(0, WhereStarts);

        // if its on the valid domain (exclude the www)
        if (cValidNames.Contains(cTheFirstPart))
        {
            // now I add in the frond the name and continue with the rest url
            string cFinalPath = "/" + cTheFirstPart + Request.RawUrl;

            // now rewrite it.
            HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(cFinalPath, false);

            return;
        }
    }
```